# passing columns into purrr::walk2()

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to save a series of models using `purrr`'s `walk()` functions, and am getting the following error:

"Error in map2(.x, .y, .f, ...) : object 'model' not found"

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

mt_models <- 
    mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(
        model = map(.x = data, .f = ~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x)),
        file_name = paste("model", cyl, "cyl.rda", sep = "_")
    ) 

mt_models %>% walk2(.x = model, .y = file_name, .f = ~save(.x, file = .y))
```

I can successfully save the models using this code below:

```
walk2(.x = mt_models$model, .y = mt_models$file_name, .f = ~save(.x, file = .y))
```

But I am trying to understand why `model` is not passing into `walk2()` in the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside the `mutate/summarise` and other tidyverse function, we need to do `.$` to extract the column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mt_models %>% {
    walk2(.x = .$model, .y = .$file_name, .f = ~save(.x, file = .y))
     }
```

Comment: what is the deal with the {} surrounding walk2()? I have never seen that before. Thank you.

Comment: @Joe It is not needed here, but I used in case of extracting more parameters

Answer (score 2):

You can use `with` to provide an environment in which to search for variables

```
mt_models %>% 
  with(walk2(.x = model, .y = file_name, .f = ~save(.x, file = .y)))
```